# Theming select file button in managed-file formfield

Tags: theming

I use a straight forward upload button (form-field of type 'managed-file), my site runs under the bootstrap theme.

The result is shown below (the blue button I added myself after the managed file field)

This does not show for customers. How can I theme this??

[image]

Comment: Be more precise please. Which version of Drupal? Put some code sample or description of how you added the button. What exactly does not show?

Comment: Found out that it  only happens in Firefox. Chrome and Safari are OK. It happens with just rendering the upload form-field:         $publicPath='public://upload';

        $form['file'] = [
          '#title' => 'Selecteer de te uploaden file',
          '#type' => 'managed_file',
          '#upload_location' => $publicPath,
          '#upload_validators' => [
            'file_validate_extensions' => ['docx gif png jpg jpeg'],
          ]];